# Hartl Rails Tutorial Ch9, "test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

Working through Hartl's tutorial, in Chapter 9, Listing 9.56 produces the following error, showing 'admin?' as an undefined method.

I've checked (and rechecked) the 2 sections of code that have been revised since the last green test. Stumped.

```
 ERROR["test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in", UsersControllerTest, 2016-02-26 21:29:01 -0500]
 test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in#UsersControllerTest (1456540141.41s)
NoMethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
            app/controllers/users_controller.rb:73:in `admin_user'
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
            test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:47:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
        app/controllers/users_controller.rb:73:in `admin_user'
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
        test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:47:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'

  39/39: [==========================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.97767s
39 tests, 152 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Note that the admin field was added to the database during a migration, which I understand *should* automatically produce a boolean admin? method

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

users_controller_test.rb is where the problem apparently resides, specifically in the lines:

```
test "should redirect destroy when not logged in" do
  assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
  delete :destroy, id: @user
```

...while the complete file looks like this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup
    @user       = users(:michael)
    @other_user = users(:archer)
  end

  test "should redirect index when not logged in" do
    get :index
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should redirect edit when not logged in" do
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect to update when not logged in" do
    patch :update, id: @user, user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect edit when logged in as wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when logged in as wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    patch :update, id: @user, user: {name: @user.name, email: @user.email }
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

  test "should redirect destroy when not logged in" do
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      delete :destroy, id: @user
    end
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect destroy when logged in as a non-admin" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      delete :destroy, id: @user
    end
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end
end
```

and here's the contents of users.yaml

```
# Read about fixtures at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html

michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  admin: true

archer:
  name: Sterling Archer
  email: duchess@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

lana:
  name: Lana Kane
  email: hands@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

mallory:
  name: Mallory Archer
  email: boss@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

<% 30.times do |n| %>
user_<%= n %>:
  name:  <%= "User #{n}" %>
  email: <%= "user-#{n}@example.com" %>
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the error message it looks like you're calling `admin?` on `current_user` but you don't have anyone logged in, so `current_user` is nil. Try doing `current_user.try(:admin?)` instead which will return nil if current_user is also nil.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I changed the following line in `users_controller.rb` from
`redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin`
 to
`redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.try(:admin?)`

Comment: great, would you mind accepting the answer? I'd really appreciate it. (I could use the rep so I can easier respond to questions)

Comment: With pleasure. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this. Whilst bf34's answer does the trick it may not be the correct solution.

Currently doing this tutorial and had the same issue. The reason it was purely current_user.admin? is because it shouldn't even reach this check if not logged in.

After a bit of rereading of my code I discovered that I didn't have the before_action of logged_in_user for the destroy method (see second line).

***app/controllers/users_controller.rb:***

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user,  only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,    only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,      only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      # Handle a successful update.
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end

    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```